# Populating admob ad in Android without resetting a FrameLayout on the screen

Tags: android, admob, android-framelayout

I wanted to implement a sliding menu bar like the Facebook app and I used the following [github example](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo) to implement it.

I have an add Layout in all of my apps screens.
My problem is as follows:

1. I open the app.
2. I click on the icon that opens the menu
3. If app loads during the time I have opened my menu, the menu automatically closes.
4. If you click on the icon that opens the menu, the menu dances.
5. This only happens if the add loads when the menu is open.

Here is my typical layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Fill" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FL_home"
    style="@style/Fill"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView" >

    <include layout="@layout/app_com_menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL_app"
        style="@style/Fill.RL"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/app_com_title" />

        <ListView
            style="@style/FillWrap.List" />

        <include layout="@layout/network_error" />
    <include layout="@layout/error_no_live"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/ad_layout" />
```

My ad_layout file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.ads.AdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
android:visibility="gone" />
```

And this is the main logic of the sliding drawer

```
class AppMenuListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doAnimation();
    }
}

class AppMenuCloseListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (menuOut) {
            doAnimation();
        }
    }
}

private void doAnimation() {
    AppBase me = AppBase.this;
    Animation animation = null;

    int width = appPage.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = appPage.getMeasuredHeight();
    int left = (int) (appPage.getMeasuredWidth() * 0.67);
    if (menuOut) {
        if (appMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -left, 0, 0);
            animation.setDuration(300);
            animParams.set(0, 0, width, height);
        }
    } else {
        if (appMenu.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, left, 0, 0);
            appMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animParams.set(left, 0, left + width, height);
            animation.setDuration(400);
        }
    }

    animation.setAnimationListener(me);
    animation.setFillEnabled(true);
    appPage.startAnimation(animation);
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    menuOut = !menuOut;
    if (!menuOut) {
        appMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    appPage.layout(animParams.left, animParams.top, animParams.right,
            animParams.bottom);
}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

static class AnimParams {
    int left, right, top, bottom;

    void set(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }
}
```

I tried using an adListener and stopping ads from loading if menu is out but I didn't have much luck there.

Can someone suggest me what I can do different?